# Autoit click on button which is on Frame

Tags: autoit

can someone please help me with my code , im trying to click on "Setup" text but this is on Frame , so i dont know how to do that , thank you

my not working code :

```
#include <Array.au3>

Run("C:\Program Files\ESET\ESET Endpoint Antivirus\egui.exe")
Sleep(2000)
Global $hWnd = WinGetHandle("egui.exe")
Global $hWnd = WinWait('ESET Endpoint Antivirus')

If Not $hWnd Then
    MsgBox(16, "Error", "ESET Endpoint Antivirus window not found")
    Exit
EndIf

ControlClick('ESET Endpoint Antivirus','','[TEXT:Tools]')
Sleep(1000)
ControlClick('ESET Endpoint Antivirus','','[TEXT:Setup]')
ControlClick("ESET Endpoint Antivirus","", "")


; Title:    ESET Endpoint Antivirus
; Class:    ESET Main Frame
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code for Eset Gui(version 10.1.2050.0).

For going to : Setup ==> Advanced Setup==> Update ==> Profiles ==>  Updates ==> Modules Updates

```
#include <Array.au3>
#RequireAdmin
AutoItSetOption("MouseCoordMode", 0)
Run("C:\Program Files\ESET\ESET Security\egui.exe")
Sleep(500)
WinWait('ESET Endpoint Antivirus')
WinActivate('ESET Endpoint Antivirus')
MouseClick('primary', 77, 216,2)
Sleep(500)
MouseClick('primary', 943, 649,2)
WinWait('Advanced setup - ESET Endpoint Antivirus')
MouseClick('primary', 42, 201,2)
Sleep(500)
MouseMove(272,103,2)
MouseClick('primary')
Sleep(500)
ConsoleWrite("Hello World" & @CRLF)
ConsoleWrite("dddd" & @CRLF)
MouseClick('primary',288,157)   
MouseClick('primary',302,287)  
MouseClick('primary',669,528)
```